# Filter nested/inline collection using @PostFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm having trouble filtering a nested/inline collection using the `@PostFilter` annotation. My data model is like this:

```
+--------+ 1   * +----------+ 1   * +---------------+
| Course |------>| Exercise |------>| Participation |
+--------+       +----------+       +===============+
                                    | user: String  |
                                    +---------------+
```

I basically only want to include only those participations in the JSON response for which the user equals the currently authenticated user.

I have overridden the `findAll` methods in my repository interface which extends `CrudRepository`, and added the `@PostFilter` annotation:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface ParticipationRepository extends CrudRepository<Participation, Long> {

  @Override
  @PostFilter("filterObject.user == principal.username")
  Iterable<Participation> findAll();

  @Override
  @PostFilter("filterObject.user == principal.username")
  Iterable<Participation> findAll(Iterable<Long> longs);
}
```

I have also tried to add the annotation on the getter method for the participations inside the exercise class.

With Spring Security debugging turned on I can however see that the PostFilter expression is never applied. I guess this might be because Spring Data Rest doesn't use one of the methods I annotated for getting the participations.

Has anybody faced similar issues and found a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `@Pre*`/`@Post*` annotations work at all?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `@PostFilter` on the course repository and it's working fine.

Comment: Did you find an answer? It is not working in my code and I have no clue how to debug it ither.